# where to add code for disabling OPTIONS method in apache

Tags: server, apache2

a web application security assessment recommends me to `disable OPTIONS method on the webserver`

im running Apache/2.2.22(ubuntu)

The solution i found so far was to add this certain code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(POST|GET)\ /.*\ HTTP/1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

im quite confused where to add this specific code, i have 3 `.conf` on my `/etc/apache2`

- apache2.conf
- httpd.conf
- ports.conf

do i just add the snippet anywhere inside the `.conf` file?

---

[edit]

after adding the config on my `apache2.conf` OR `httpd.conf` im getting this error when i try to restart

```
Invalid command 'RewriteCond', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.

The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

---

[edit2]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://192.168.5.1/web/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.5.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Are you using `virtual hosts` for your sites?

Comment: no. i just access my website by 'IP/website'

Answer (score 1):

If you have configured `vhosts` for your site you can add inside your required `vhosts`. If not you can simply add to `httpd.conf` if not exists add to `apache2.conf` file.

Comment: ok, so after i add the code. how do i check if its implemented? or how do i check if the code is working?

Comment: You can make request using `curl` to your website like `PUT` `DELETE` they will surely give `403 Forbidden` except for
`POST`, `GET`.

Comment: hi, can you check my edit above? i seem to be getting some kind of error when i try to add the code and restart the server.

Comment: Try to add in `apache2.conf` and where you have pasted the code? Please add code to the last line of document. It seems working here.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that i need to enable `rewrite` first. it accepts the code. now im getting `301 Moved Permanently`

Comment: @user1666411 Ok its going off topic now. Your question was just about disabling `SERVER` Request Methods and where to add them. Now you should ask another question how to check that certain methods that are enable or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11925/discussion-between-rahil-wazir-and-user1666411)